# Not getting right coordinates for UIAccessibilityElement

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to do grouping of my button with my label but not getting the rectangle for accessibility at right place.

After swiping all the way to get to the element, it takes right width and height but y-position is completely wrong. It speaks the right VO but I don't know why position is incorrect. I have following code,

```
let checkboxAccessible = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: view)
let unionRect = passwordCheckbox.frame.union(showPasswordText.frame)
checkboxAccessible.accessibilityFrame = UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates(unionRect, self.view)
checkboxAccessible.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("Show Password", comment: "showPasswordText")
view.accessibilityElements = [productTitle, leadInText, emailTextField, passwordTextField, checkboxAccessible, loginButton, forgotPasswordView, helpButton]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue where I was having a `StackView` which had two `IBOutlets` (Let's say a **title** and a **value**). And I had been struggling for months and couldn't figure out why my container couldn't find the correct position of the frame (`self.frame`).

Recently when I came back trying to solve this, I saw the [Apple documenation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app) that they were using `union()` function. I tried it out in my case and it worked perfectly!

#### Example of working grouped elements:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    
    private var _accessibilityElements: [Any]?
    override var accessibilityElements: [Any]? {
        set {
            _accessibilityElements = newValue
        }
        
        get {
            guard _accessibilityElements == nil else {
                return _accessibilityElements
            }
            
            var elements = [UIAccessibilityElement]()
            
            guard let titleText = titleLabel.text,
                let valueText = valueLabel.text else {
                    return elements
            }
            
            let latitudeElement = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self)
            latitudeElement.accessibilityLabel = "\(titleText), \(valueText)"
            latitudeElement.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = titleLabel.frame.union(valueLabel.frame) // Before: "self.frame"
            elements.append(latitudeElement)
            _accessibilityElements = elements
            
            return _accessibilityElements
        }
    }
    
    func removeAccessibilityElements() {
        _accessibilityElements = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found what was the mistake I was making. All above mentioned changes were in ViewDidLoad and by that time we were not getting correct frame.

So I made those changes in viewDidLayoutSubviews now getting the correct frame.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned Jacob Ahlberg, it is smth wrong when using `UIStackView`, but in my case it is incorrect frame when using `UIStackView` in `UIScrollView`. The best solution is to use `UICollectionView` instead but you can update accessibilityFrame every time on `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method of `UIScrollViewDelegate`. Then it will be updated correctly. Also it is possible to solve the problem by using `accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace`